# Prove subset is not a subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that subset $S=\{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | -da + bc=0\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Though I am really confused with the way to prove it.

I kind of think that I am on the right track, but I feel that I am doing something completely wrong. I am really new to this topic, so I would really appreciate if you could help. Thank you

Comment: Without dividing, I think it is pretty clear that $(0,0,0,0)$ is in your set. So that's not the problem.

Comment: @ArcticChar I agree. But it also doesn't work if you try to show that it is not closed under addition or multiplication by scalar, so I have attempted to do it this way. I can see that the "vector relationship" (sorry if I am using some very wrong terminology) - ad=bc -  is not linear, so this can't be a linear subspace, can it? but I don't know how to show it formally - the only formal proofs of whether a subset is a subspace I have discovered use these - is {0} a subset?is it closed under addition&multiplication by scalar?

Comment: Your implication only works if $a \neq 0$.  That's a clue as to how to make addition fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without dividing, I think it is pretty clear that $(0,0,0,0)$ is in $S$. So that's not the problem. You can also check directly from the definition that if $(a, b, c, d)$ is in $S$, then the same is $t(a, b, c, d)$ for any real number $t$.

So the only problem is the additivity. You will need to find two elements $(a_1, b_1, c_1, d_1)$, $(a_2, b_2, c_2, d_2)$ in $S$, so that the addition

$$(a_1 +a_2, b_1+b_2, c_1+c_2, d_1+d_2)$$
is NOT in $S$: that is, you do not have

$$ -(d_1+d_2)(a_1+a_2) + (b_1+b_2)(c_1+c_2) = 0.$$

Comment: oh, okey. so if I bring a counterexample like this, will it be enough?

for $S_1=(0,1,0,2), S_2=(1,0,1,0)$ s.t. $S_1,S_2 \in S$ 
$$S_1 +S_2 = -(2+0)(1+0) + (1+0)(1+0) = -1 $$
$$\implies -da + bc \ne 0$$

Comment: Yes, you nailed it. @Yo0

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample would be sufficient proof to show that this is not a subspace.

Take the case of:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \& \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Both of these vectors would be in $S$ but their sum will not be since $-(1)(1)+(0)(0)\neq 0$. Since the addition property is violated, $S$ is not  a subspace.